# Spring Boot - @ConditionalOnExpression for @RestController

Tags: java, spring, rest

I want to enable/disable a `@RestController` based on configuration, in order achieve it i'm trying to use the `@ConditionalOnExpression` annotation.

Using a static hardcoded value is working just fine:

```
@RestController
@ConditionalOnExpression("true")
public class MyRestController {

    @RequestMapping("/hi")
    public String hi() {
        return "hi";
    }
}
```

Yet, using a dynamic property value within a SpEL expression always results in **not** loading the `@RestController`:

```
@RestController
@ConditionalOnExpression("${my.rest.controller.enabled:false}")
public class MyRestController { ... }
```

Would really appreciate any ideas/best practices to resolve this.

Answer (score 5):

To verify that a property in Spring Cloud Config is not provided, I used the following expression:

```
  /**
   * @return The Jms Template for sending the messages to the queue.
   */
  @Bean(name = "jmsTemplate")
  @ConditionalOnExpression("!'${jsk.messaging.jms.queue}'.isEmpty()")
  public JmsTemplate jmsTemplateForQueues() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory);
    return jmsTemplate;
  }
```

Comment: For spring 2.1 it needs a colon (so that the default value is empty)

Comment: @ThomasRS What scenario does it need?

Answer (score 4):

Best way to use **ConditionalOnProperty** annotation for property based conditions.

Here is example :

```
@RestController
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix="my.rest.controller", name="enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class MyRestController { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

The spring expression language requires an expression to be evaluated. I've found that using :false to specify the ConditionalOnExpression doesn't evaluate properly for some reason, so I can suggest a couple of ways to work around this problem.

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${my.rest.controller.enabled}==false")
// or
@ConditionalExpression("!${my.rest.controller.enabled}")
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, the problem is that web components, and @RestController among them, are initialized pre-configurations hence the ${value} will always be null.

Comment: @ranweiz How you resolved it ? in my case controller is always working even I used @ConditionalOnExpression("1==0")

Answer (score 0):

I think that expression like 
`@ConditionalOnExpression("${my.rest.controller.enabled:false}")`

is very missleading. The ':false' part is telling that if there is no my.rest.controller.enabled property, whole expression should be evaluated to 'false'

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Sploink.
You can try using

`@ConditionalOnExpression("#{${my.rest.controller.enabled}==true}")`